# How to improve the performace of bigace3 website

Tags: php, performance

I have used `bigace3` for creating my website, but when I tried to load my site its taking so much time to load for the first time and after that the performance was good since it is cached.
I need suggestions to make my site to load faster for the first time without any cache.I have minified the js,css using compressors.Even though its taking 2 minutes to load my home page. Please suggest me how can I make my site to load much faster.

Comment: open developer too `F12` go to networks tab, see which file or item is taking long to respond.

Comment: I have even tried it using yslow plugin the data itself is taking time to load.The waiting time is more

Answer (score 0):

even if you minify the css or js the file size might still be high. Try to gzip the files before its sent to browser this should definitely improve the performance. This is supported by all the modern browser and may not work properly in old browsers like IE 6. You can specify not to gzip for old browsers if thats required. Once you gzip css or js then in response you will see an additional header as "Content-Encoding:gzip".